# How to return a std::vector from a method and not have it be a copy every time?

Tags: c++

I'm pretty sure this is some pointer business, but I've been out of C++ for a while.

Basically, I have a class with a method `getVector()` that returns a `std::vector` it has stored as a class variable.

I want to access these elements, but not copy the whole vector every time `getVector()` is called.  What is the correct approach to this?  The vector stored as a class variable is not a pointer itself.

Comment: Whenever I see questions like this, I get the sneaking suspicion that the asker hasn't understood the concept of encapsulation.  But I haven't seen your code, so I can't be sure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Return a *reference* to the vector.**

1. If the calling scope should be able to modify the vector:

   ```
   class MyClass {
       std::vector<foo> v;

     public:
       std::vector<foo>& getVector() {
          return v;
       }
   };
   ```
2. If the calling scope does not need to modify the vector:

   ```
   class MyClass {
       std::vector<foo> v;

     public:
       const std::vector<foo>& getVector() const {
          return v;
       }
   };
   ```

Both are perfectly "safe" since the vector is not local to the function scope.

Comment: That's the ticket.  Thanks a tonne!

Comment: @Tomalak: timing issue: it didn't at the time I answered, that's why I deleted my comment before I saw your comment.  Your initial answer was a one-liner stating that a reference could be returned.

Comment: @stefaanv: Must have been some rendering fault in your browser! :P Really, my answer was complete a full 3 minutes 26 seconds before you posted your comment.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal question, why the double const?  Why isn't having only the const before the brace sufficient?

Comment: @zebra: One is for the return type, and the other is for the member function. It's not a "double" `const`. Your suggestion is wrong because [a non-`const` ref to a member cannot be obtained from a `const`-context](http://codepad.org/rWDDB7tj) (this would trivially violate `const`-correctness).

Comment: @zebra Because that won't let you return a mutable reference to the vector, since in a const method the `this` pointer and therefore all members are const, so you can (and should and want) only return a const reference to the vector.

Answer (score 4):

Well, if the calling code can access the vector, why is the vector a private attribute?  If you make it a public attribute, then there is no need for the getVector() method, is there?

If you want the vector to be a prvate attribute for some good reason, then you should not give such open access, but provide methods to modify the private data as appropriate.

The nearest thing to providing open access, while still keeping the vector private, is to give access to the iterator

```
typedef std::vector<foo>::iterator iterator_foo
iterator_foo begin_foo() { return v.begin(); }
iterator_foo end_foo() { return v.end(); }
```

Which you can use as follows

```
MyClass::iterator_foo ifoo = std::find(
   theclass.begin_foo(), theclass.end_foo(), foo_target );
if ( ifoo != theclass.end_foo() ) {
   cout << "found it" << endl;
   ....
```

Comment: +1: I agree; this is a canonically _poor_ use of getters. "Every property must be shielded behind a getter!" >.<